# How to use Code value in the info.plist file xcode ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, info.plist

I want to use some custom constants in info.plist file to use it globally 
e.g

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>$(my_custom_constant)</string>
```

1. how to make this constant?
2. how can I differentiate it by selecting debug and release mode.e.g. FacebookAppID is "abc" for debug mode and "xyz" for release mode.

Comment: `info.plist` is readonly in runtime, what is your goal here?

Comment: I was using facebook API in my app and I made 2 diff apps on fb one for debugging and other one for release. whenever i make release build I have to make change in info.plist as well. I just want to make my release build by just one click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the variable by adding it as a "User-Defined Setting" to your target, in Build Settings. You can then set the variable value to different things for each of your build configurations.

Please see attached screenshot. You can ignore my Beta Prod and Beta Test configurations, as they probably don't apply to your situation.

[image]

Comment: I did: "You can then set the variable value to different things for each of your build configurations." So set it to 2 for your Debug configuration, and 3, for your Release configuration.

Answer (score 6):

Set your custom variable in info.plist as shown below. I have taken "HockeyAppID" as example here.

[image]

Next, Add a variable in Build Settings under "User-Defined" for Debug and Release configuration in your case as shown below. Here, I have my own four different configurations.

[image]

As you know, different configuration values will be loaded at runtime based on the settings in scheme.
In order to access HockeyAppId for Debug / Release configuration from info.plist, do the following.

```
 enum InfoPlistKey {
   static let hockeyappID = "HockeyAppID"
 }

 struct AppSettings {

   private static var infoDict: [String: Any] {
      if let dict = Bundle.main.infoDictionary {
          return dict
      } else {
          fatalError("Info Plist file not found")
      }
   }

   static let hockeyAppID = infoDict[InfoPlistKey.hockeyappID] as! String
 }
```

Now, you can access HockeyAppId value from Info.plist as ,

```
let identifier = AppSettings.hockeyAppID
```

Please let me know in case of any issues.